# uninitialized constant (NameError) Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am fairly new to ruby and trying to write a gem file but the following error occurs.I have updated bundler and the relevant gems as was suggested in other posts.
Developing with

- ubuntu 18.04LTS
- ruby 2.5.1p57
- gem 3.1.2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    15: from /usr/local/bin/vcdm:23:in `<main>'
    14: from /usr/local/bin/vcdm:23:in `load'
    13: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/vcdm-0.1.2/bin/vcdm:4:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    11: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    10: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/vcdm-0.1.2/lib/vcdm.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
     8: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
     7: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/vcdm-0.1.2/lib/vcdm/command.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/vcdm-0.1.2/lib/vcdm/command.rb:4:in `<module:Vcdm>'
     5: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/vcdm-0.1.2/lib/vcdm/command.rb:4:in `glob'
     4: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     3: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     2: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/vcdm-0.1.2/lib/vcdm/commands/hostfile.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/vcdm-0.1.2/lib/vcdm/commands/hostfile.rb:5:in `<module:Vcdm>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/vcdm-0.1.2/lib/vcdm/commands/hostfile.rb:14:in `<class:HostfileCommand>': uninitialized constant Vcdm::HostfileCommand::CommandOption (NameError)
```

These are my code what I am tring to execute 
**command_option.rb**

```
module Vcdm

  class CommandOption
    attr_reader :name, :type, :description

    def initialize(name, type, description)
      @name = name
      @type = type
      @description = description
    end

  end

end
```

**hostfile.rb**

```
require 'vcdm/command_interface'

module Vcdm
  class HostfileCommand
    as = CommandOption.new("--path STRING", String, "custom hosts path")

    IS_PUBLIC_COMMAND = true
    SYNTAX = 'vcdm hostfile'
    SUMMARY = 'adds the ingress url to the users hostfile'
    DESCRIPTION = ""
    EXAMPLE = "vcdm hostfile --path=/mnt/c/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts"
    EXAMPLE_DESCRIPTION = ""
    implements CommandInterface

  end

end
```

**command_interface.rb**

```
require 'class_interface'

class CommandInterface
  IS_PUBLIC_COMMAND = true | false
  SYNTAX = String
  SUMMARY = String
  DESCRIPTION = String
  EXAMPLE = String
  EXAMPLE_DESCRIPTION = String
  OPTIONS = Array

  def initialize
  end

  def execute(args, options)
  end

end
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: It is assuming CommandOption to be: `Vcdm::HostfileCommand::CommandOption`, try changing CommandOption in hostfile.rb line 5 to Vcdm::CommandOption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels to me like you are missing a

```
require 'vcdm/command_option'
```

in your `hostfile.rb`. Just add that line to the top of that file.

Answer (score 0):

try putting this in 'config/application.rb'

```
config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

and then in 'hostfile.rb'

```
require 'vcdm/command_interface'

module Vcdm
  include CommandOption
  class HostfileCommand
  ...
```

Comment: But I didn't have any config/application.rb

Comment: I see... try adding the include then.

Comment: got the ```uninitialized constant Vcdm::HostfileCommand (NameError)
```

Comment: wait, my bad... can you 'include CommandOption' above class HostfileCommand

Comment: same error ```uninitialized constant Vcdm::CommandOption (NameError)```

Comment: add require on top of the file: require '/home/.../<fullpath>/vcdm/command_option'

Comment: @user2006506 You do not have a `config/application.rb`? You tagged your question with `ruby-on-rails`. What version of Ruby on Rails are you using that doesn't need a `config/application.rb`?